# What could be causing random spikes of redis commands/second and latency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, newrelic, datadog

I'm using Datadog and NewRelic to try and track down odd behavior that seems to happen at random times. Recently I have noticed huge spikes in REDIS latency to my application in NewRelic. I added Datadog to the Redis server and saw these spikes of commands/second going from around ~0.5-2k to over 40-60k! Along with those is a spike in bandwidth and load, but only very mindor CPU changes.

When these were occurring, GoogleAnalytics (GA) was actually showing a rather slow day in comparison. In fact, the overall app load today is about 2-3x higher than the day shown in the image below, but today has had perfect REDIS performance without any latency/commands spikes.

Could it be bots/crawlers hitting stale caches that are causing large chunks of data to be inserted at once? My app heavily relies on an external API, which does occasionally spike in response time as well, but why would a slow API call cause slower redis calls or massive spikes in redis commands?

[image: Showing very mild CPU spikes, but large Commands/Second and Bandwidth spikes]

[image: NewRelic showing Redis latency spikes]